# saving the images with in application - android

Tags: android, image

i am developing an application where i need to capture the pictures from camera and save them with in application like in this location "/data/data/com...../images" - what i want to know is this the right approach . if not please suggest but my images should not be available to other app's.

Thanks and Regards,
puneeth

Answer (score 0):

I think every approach have their drawbacks. If the picture should always be there (unless delete through app), I feel it may not be best approach. Otherwise it is Ok to use this approach (which is what I am doing too). Only caution I took was, if picture was deleted by someone, always have a default picture to display there (which saves application crash and other alignment issues).

Answer (score 0):

You’re talking about the [Context.getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) directory. Note that, on older phones with separate SD card storage, this area is likely to be quite limited in size, so be careful about saving lots of images here. You may want to use [getExternalCacheDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29) or [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) instead.